# How to change the name of my application for Evernote?

Tags: evernote

We developped an application that works with Evernote. When we created the api Key, we had to choose a name for our application.

Now, I would like to change this application name. How, who, where can I ask for that ?

I searched on https://dev.evernote.com/, but found no way to submit a support ticket, only links to forums, FAQs.

In this [discussion](https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/105062-i-want-to-change-my-app-name/), we are encouraged to create a question on StackOverflow. Quoting Phils :

> You'll need to post that request in StackOverflow, as that's the place
>   where Evernote developer support has designated.

So, here is my question

Comment: Try one of them http://dev.evernote.com/support/

Comment: this link redirects either to the dev forum, or to StackOverflow. I also added a post on this topic : https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/105062-i-want-to-change-my-app-name/